# Unable to push Docker Container to Azure Kubernetes Service from Jenkins job build

Tags: azure, jenkins, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am new to Azure and Kubernetes and was trying out the following tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-from-github-to-aks#create-a-jenkins-project, however at the last part to deploy the docker to AKS I was unable to do so and faced with errors. I am not familiar with the `kubectl set image` command and have been going around the web to look for solutions but to no avail. I would appreciate if you could share your knowledge if you have experience the following issue previously.

The following is the configuration: (NOTE: The docker image is able to push to ACR successfully)

[image]

The following is the error following the jenkins build job:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an existing deployment called docker-demo? (check with kubectl get deployments)

Comment: I have checked and do not have any deployment with this name. After deploying the deployment with this name, it is working fine. However, I was not able to do so by running the ```kubectl create deployment docker-demo``` command in the execute shell section of jenkins. NOTE: I have included the deployment.yml in my project in Git.

Comment: Of course not. The kubectl create deployment syntax expects more arguments than just the name. Kubectl set expects the item to already exist - which it didn't before. You won't need to "recreate" the deployment once it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you missed in the initial article you provided the steps, where they deploy app before Jenkin usage.
Look, first of all they [Deploy azure-vote-front application to AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-from-github-to-aks#deploy-the-sample-application-to-aks)

```
containers:
- name: azure-vote-front
  image: microsoft/azure-vote-front:v1
```

And of course Jenkins will see this deployment during `kubectl set image deployment/azure-vote-front azure-vote-front=$WEB_IMAGE_NAME --kubeconfig /var/lib/jenkins/config`

So please, create a deployment first as @mmking and common sense suggest.